# How to get the LayoutManager of a closed dwg file in Autocad?

Tags: .net, autocad

For Autocad in .Net, I have a folder containing dwg files and I want to delete the layouts that are in each file except the "Model" and "Layout1". I am using this code for the opened file in Autocad:

```
public void RemoveLayout(Transaction transaction, Database database, ObjectId layoutId)
{
    if (!layoutId.IsErased)
    {
        Layout layout = transaction.GetObject(layoutId, OpenMode.ForRead) as Layout;
        LayoutManager.Current.DeleteLayout(layout.LayoutName);
    }
  }
```

But, When I try to open the documents that are in my folder and set the document to active:

```
Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.Open(file, false);
Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument = doc;
```

The `LayoutManager.current` still point to the my first document, so I can't delete the wanted layout using the code below:

```
LayoutManager.Current.DeleteLayout(layout.LayoutName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `Session` to your command flags. And the document needs to be explicitly locked:

```
[CommandMethod("YOURCOMMAND", CommandFlags.Session)]
public void YourCommand()
{
  [..]
  Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.Open(file);
  // No need here to set MdiActiveDocument, it's done by the Open method.
  using (doc.LockDocument())
  using (Transaction tr = doc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
  {
    LayoutManager.Current.DeleteLayout("Your layout name");
    tr.Commit();
  }
}
```